# Blackbody temperature with redshift confusion

Tags: thermal-radiation, redshift

I am a little confused about proving that the temperature of a redshifted blackbody differs from the intrinsic temperature by the factor (where z is the reshift)$$T=\frac{T_{intrinsic}}{(1+z)}$$ 
  So I've been looking in various sources finding all sorts of proofs that at a certain point seem to contradict each other.I will be listing below 3 proofs that I found:

FIRST PROOF:

This one is usually used in cosmology and uses the first law of thermodynamics and the fact that in its expansion, the universe evolves adiabatically:
$$dQ=dU+dL$$
$$dQ=0 \implies dU=-dL$$
The energy density of a universe filled with radiation is $$u=\frac{4\sigma}{c}T^4$$
And the radiation pressure is $$p=\frac{u}{3}$$
$$ dL=pdV$$ and $$dU=d(uV)$$ and $$V=\frac{4\pi R_0^3 a^3}{3}$$ where where "a" is the scale factor and "R0" is the present radius of the universe.Substituting everywhere we obtain that $$\frac{dT}{T}=\frac{da}{a}$$ and knowing that $$a=\frac{constant}{1+z} \implies T_0 =\frac{T}{1+z} $$ 
where "T0" is the present temperature of the universe

SECOND PROOF:

This is the proof with which I am the most pleased ( also used in cosmology ). We can express the luminosity of a black body as:
$$L=\frac{dN}{dt} \cdot \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$ 
where dN/dt represents photons emited per unit time.Because with the expansion of the universe all distances strech we know that :
$$ dt=\frac{constant}{a} ; dN =constant ; \lambda=constant\cdot a$$
where a is the scale factor. We also know that the distance between us and the body increases with 1+z so the observed flux(watts per unit area) will therefor be :

$$F=\frac{L_{intrinsic}}{4 \pi r_{initial}^2 (1+z)^4}$$ 
This is actually what we observe and this is the definiton of the luminosity distance $$d_L=r_{initial} (1+z)^2$$

THIRD PROOF (no more expansion of the universe)

The Planck distribution law is:
$$ B_\lambda=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda kT}-1}$$
$$B_{\lambda_0}=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda_0^5}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda_0 kT_0}-1}$$

If we take a redshifted blackbody we have :
$$\lambda=(1+z)\lambda_0$$

The integrated intensities(over the entire spectrum) are :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} B_{\lambda_0} d\lambda_0 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda_0^5}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda_0 kT_0}-1}d\lambda_0$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} B_{\lambda} d\lambda= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda kT}-1}d\lambda = \frac{1}{(1+z)^4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda_0^5}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda_0 (1+z) kT}-1}d\lambda_0$$
Now if we assume $$T=\frac{T_0}{1+z}$$
And after integrating we obtain the new luminosity(watts) of the blackbody:
$$L=\frac{L_0}{(1+z)^4}$$ 
proving the assumption right:
$$T=\frac{T_0}{1+z}$$

My question is why in the second proof the luminosity is less by a factor of $(1+z)^2$ and not $(1+z)^4$ like in the third one. ( in the second proof $(1+z)^2$ also comes from the distance expansion)

Thank you!